# How to resume simulations running in background?

Tags: linux, nohup, simulation

I am running long-term transient simulations on a server. For making them to run in background, I use the command `nohup` from the netlist folder of the corresponding schematic.

Tonight they got interrupted, due to insufficient space on the disk.

I have solved the problem with the disk. I would like to resume them, to make them to start again from that point, without losing the data already there.

Comment: Adding the vendor name of the simulation software and specific module to the question may help getting a specific answer.

Answer (score 0):

If jobs were interrupted due to insufficient disk space, they most likely exited completely. This depends on the way they were programmed, but I can't imagine any process waiting for user input before exiting due to failed write operations or other symptoms of a full disk.

There's no way to "resume" other than starting the processes again.

The only possibility you have is when the process (whatever it is) is aware of what output it has already produced and where it needs to start again. For example, the process could scan its output for already existing items and then continue where it left off. But no process does this by default, you need to explicitly program it this way.

It all depends on what exactly this process is, what it takes as input, and what output it produces (so, if we knew that, we could probably help you better).

Answer (score 0):

Check the simulator documentation to see if it implements a `checkpoint` feature, and if it was enabled during your simulation. The documentation should describe how to *resume/restart/continue* from last good checkpoint.